# Optimize query performance in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query :

```
SELECT 
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[SOCIETE],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[DATE_COMPTABILISATION],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[TYPE_DOCUMENT],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[NUM_DOCUMENT],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[DESIGNATION],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[CODE_JOURNAL],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[MONTANT],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[MONTANT_DEBIT],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[MONTANT_CREDIT],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[TYPE_ORIGINE],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[NUM_ORIGINE],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[MONTANT_TVA],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[GROUPE_COMPTA_PRODUIT],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[GROUPE_COMPTA_MARCHE],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[LETTRE],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[TYPE_COMPTA_TVA],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[NUM_TRANSACTION],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[NUM_SEQUENCE],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[NUM_COMPTE],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[GROUPE_COMPTA_MARCHE_TVA],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[GROUPE_COMPTA_PRODUIT_TVA],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[CODE_BUDGET],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[ID],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[Dimension Value Code],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[CENTRE_COUT],
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[TYPE_COMPTE],
    CODE_TS
FROM 
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE] WITH(INDEX(DATE))
WHERE 
    [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[DATE_COMPTABILISATION] >='01/05/2014' 
AND [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[DATE_COMPTABILISATION] < '01/06/2014'
```

The query works fine but it is much too slow. Is there a way to optimize query execution time?

Comment: Does it work faster without forcing it to use the index? If the returned row count is big, adding all the fields in the query as included columns will probably help a lot, but that can have a big cost for all the updates

Comment: Is there an **index** on the `[DATE_COMPTABILISATION]` column? What does the query execution plan tell you?

Comment: @marc_s yes there is .

Comment: And how many rows does this query select - out of how many rows total?? Is this returning half the table, or only a few rows?

Comment: Does your index include other columns? Most likely not, so it probably does a Key Lookup to fetch other columns in your result set and it's quite a heavy operation.

Comment: can you post the execution plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is not so complicated, but there is at least one certain way to optimize it.

When you compare data of different types, sql server converts it all the time, on every check. You should use `CAST` or `CONVERT` to perform conversion one time in advance:

```
...
WHERE [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[DATE_COMPTABILISATION] >= CONVERT('01/05/2014', DATETIME2(7), 103)
    AND [dbo].[T_COMPTA_ECRITURE_COMPTABLE].[DATE_COMPTABILISATION] < CONVERT('01/06/2014', DATETIME2(7), 103)
```

I used `DATETIME2(7)` in this example - you'll prefer the very same type that `DATE_COMPTABILISATION` column has.
103 value at `CONVERT` params is the `dd/mm/yyyy` format. More on this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.120%29.aspx).